# Проблемы при наложении одного PNG на другое PNG с помощью GD. Как исправить?

Tags: gd, png, php

Проблемы при наложении одного PNG на другое PNG с помощью GD. Накладываю прозрачную PNG картинку (watermark) на прозрачную картинку PNG (1-й рисунок на скриншоте) и на непрозрачную PNG (2-й рисунок на скриншоте). Использую PHP и библиотеку GD. Как это исправить?
[image]

Comment: код в студию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[function.imagesavealpha](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagesavealpha.php)

[function.imagealphablending](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagealphablending.php#16005) + ImageCopy